# where to host my react fornt end and express endpoint that interact with smart contract to be fully decentralised?

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, ethereumjs, react, decentralization

where to host my react fornt end and express endpoint that interact with smart contract to be fully decentralised. Are there any option to host it decentralised any cloud provider other than traditional centralised options like aws,gcp,azure. IPFS and Storj are file storage i want to run my reactjs fornt end app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to correctly understand your question.
If you want to create a fully decentralized application I advise you to read the Ethereum book, chapter 12 : https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/12dapps.asciidoc .

Swarm is a good alternative to IPFS to host the frontend in a decentralized way :
https://ethersphere.github.io/swarm-home/ .

According to the Ethereum book :

> Due to high gas costs and the currently low block gas limit, smart contracts are not well suited to storing or processing large amounts of data. Hence, most DApps utilize off-chain data storage services, meaning they store the bulky data off the Ethereum chain, on a data storage platform. That data storage platform can be centralized (for example, a typical cloud database), or the data can be decentralized, stored on a P2P platform such as the IPFS, or Ethereum’s own Swarm platform.
> Decentralized P2P storage is ideal for storing and distributing large static assets such as images, videos, and the resources of the application’s frontend web interface (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.).

And :

> Swarm is another content-addressable P2P storage system, similar to IPFS. Swarm was created by the Ethereum Foundation, as part of the Go-Ethereum suite of tools. Like IPFS, it allows you to store files that get disseminated and replicated by Swarm nodes. You can access any Swarm file by referring to it by a hash. Swarm allows you to access a website from a decentralized P2P system, instead of a central web server.